# unable to use session data in select query

Tags: java, mysql, servlets

I trying to display the data of a user who is logged in.
I've used session to identify the user. When I use the session data in the select query to fetch the details of that user it shows null.
And there is an error in message in the console which is

Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).

Could anyone tell me where I'm doing wrong so that I could fix this and get it to work.
Thank you.

Display.java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;


@WebServlet("/display")
public class display extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String uname;


    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) 
            throws IOException,ServletException{
                processRequset (request,response);
            }

            public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                    throws ServletException, IOException {

                processRequset (request,response);
            }

            public void processRequset(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) 
                    throws IOException,ServletException{
                response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
                PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
                 HttpSession session=request.getSession(false);  
                    if(session!=null){  
                    String name=(String)session.getAttribute("uname");  
                    out.print("Hello, "+name+" ");  
        try {
            response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  
            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(  
            "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/register","root","toor"); 


            PreparedStatement pstmt=con.prepareStatement(  
            "select * from headwy where uname='"+ name +"'" ); 
            out.print("Hello, "+uname+" ");
             pstmt.setString(1,uname);
            ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery(); 
            out.println("<html><body><table BORDER=\"10\" WIDTH=\"50%\" bordercolor = \"green\"  CELLPADDING=\"8\"  CELLSPACING=\"3\"   ALIGN=\"CENTER\"  ><tr><td>phone</td><td>unamr</td><td>pass</td></tr>");
            while(rs.next())
            {
            out.println("<tr>  <td>"+rs.getString(1)+"</td>    <td>"+rs.getString(2)+"</td><td>"+rs.getString(3)+"</td></tr>");


            }

            out.println("</table></body></html>");
        }
          catch (Exception e2) {System.out.println(e2);
           }  

    }
                    else{  
                        out.print("Please login first");  
                        request.getRequestDispatcher("login.html").include(request, response);  
                    } 
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use a prepared statement, you need to put a placeholder for the statement parameters:

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(  
        "select * from headwy where uname=?");
pstmt.setString(1, name);
```

Comment: its just displays an empty table.

Comment: Nobody here is under any obligation to solve your problem buddy. You have to learn to help yourself. As it stands, your question is poorly formatted and entirely too broad. The only actionable thing in your question was the parameter error message, and I addressed that. Does your parameter get processed correctly? Does your query return results if executed directly on the database? These are all things that we cannot see in your code. With a little bit of debugging on your side, you would either be able to solve this problem by yourself, or provide enough information for others to help you.